# Getting output rectangle of drawBitmap has drawn a Bitmap using a Matrix

Tags: android

```
Bitmap b;

Matrix mMatrix;

    mMatrix.reset();

            // move the view so that it's center point is located in 0,0
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-sizeX, -sizeY);

            // scale the view
            mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);


            // re-move the view to it's desired location
            mMatrix.postTranslate(mTouchX, mTouchY);

            canvas.drawBitmap(b, mMatrix, null);
```

I need to know if there is an built in method to tell the info like corner coordinates of where the Bitmap is printed, etc.

Hope it is clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's called `mapRect` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapRect(android.graphics.RectF)

```
RectF r = new RectF(0, 0, b.getHeight(), b.getWidth());
mMatrix.mapRect(r);

// r now have the coordinates where the bitmap was drawn,
// you can test it by calling
canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
```